# DC 5V to Audio Line Level

Tags: audio, dc

Firstly, I'm a hobbyist and have a lot to learn.

I'm trying to get a 0-5V signal created by a microcontroller to +/-2V audio level.

I don't want to spend a lot and would like to keep the part count down, so I started experimenting using resistor dividers and I can get it into either the 0-2V or 0-4V range.

But I don't know how to make the signal go negative.  What are some ways to do that?

Comment: You can't get negative voltage out of positive supply using resistors (unless considering different reference).

Comment: I wondered if that was the case.  I'm looking for other solutions.

Comment: If you AC-couple it and keep the level down a bit you can easily fit it into ±2V RMS.

Comment: But then consider the filtering properties as well.

Comment: What does AC-coupling look like?

Comment: A capacitor large enough to not kill your low frequencies.

Comment: How can I compute that?  And I suppose the capacitor is in series with the 5V audio line?

Comment: \$f = {1 \over 2\pi R C}\$ Set \$f\$ to the lowest frequency desired, \$R\$ to the input impedance of the next stage, solve for \$C\$, and then put a device at least that large in series with the output.

Comment: Hmm. The next stage is an audio jack.  Wikipedia says "Line outputs usually present a source impedance of from 100 to 600 ohms."  Is that what I need for R?

Comment: No, you need the impedance of the next stage. Typical impedance for headphones is 32ohm.

Comment: To cancel the effect of the load you can put an amplifier stage with designed input impedance. But it will get your circuit a way more complicated.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Is it correct that the capacitor should be ceramic?

Comment: Electrolytic capacitors are commonly used for this. Try to find a bipolar if you can though.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to make an assumption here because you didn't provide enough information.

Specifically, I assume that this is an analog signal that ranges from 0V through +5V.

The solution is simple.  All you need to do is to capacitively-couple the signal from the controller output network into your destination device.

I'm going to make a couple more assumptions here:

1) The output impedance from the controller and its output network is fairly low.

2) The input impedance of the device that you are trying to feed is fairly high.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBq2ZR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm showing a polarized capacitor because that is the most common.  The (+) side of the capacitor goes to the node with the most positive (highest) *average* DC voltage.  That would be from your microcontroller: the average voltage is about 2.5 Vdc assuming that the signal swings all the way from 0V to 5V.

It's really that simple!

Comment: What is the 10KΩ resistor for?

Comment: @SamWashburn: If your destination is say an opamp, you will need a resistor to have DC path for its input bias current. Otherwise [funny problems](http://www.analog.com/library/analogDialogue/archives/41-08/amplifier_circuits.html) can occur. Also the cap needs to discharge somehow when you pull the power or else it can give nasty pops when plug stuff in again if it's charged. A resistor is the simplest way to ensure that.